# Did any deities ever incarnate as demons and plants?

Tags: identification-request, avatars, plants, demon

Everyone know that many deities took incarnation as humans, devas and sometimes animals. But, Did any deities incarnate as demons and plants?

Answer (score 3):

- [Jalandhara](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226155.html) and [Andhaka](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226183.html) are Shivansha.
- From Vrinda 3 plants were born.

Sri Shiva Purana 2.5.5.26.:

> 46. **Out of the seeds sown (on Vrinda's pyre), O great sage, three plants shot up—the Myrobalan, the Jasmine and the holy basil (Tulsi).**

- Sankhachura is a partial incarnation of Lord Vishnu who is Sudama. Mata Lakshmi became Tulsi.

Srimad Devi Bhagwatam 9.6.:

> 45. O Lakṣmī! Let you be born in parts, without being born in any womb, in the world as the daughter in the house of the King Dharma-dhvaja. **You will have to take the form of a tree there,** out of this evil turn of fate. **There Śaṅkhacūḍa, the Indra of the Asuras, born of my parts will marry you.** After that you will come back here and be my wife as now. There is no doubt in this. **You will be named Tulasī,...**

I hope this helps. Prd..

Comment: But, Vrinda is not a deity

Comment: From her funeral pyre (ashes) with the help of 3 seeds of Tridevis, 3 plants of 3 gunas were born. Sometimes She is considered an expansion of Gauri or Lakshmi. Vrindavan is said to be the personification of Lakshmi. Plus, if u think the story 3 plants came out can be considered as Ganga, Lakshmi, Saraswati and thus, the Sankhachuda story can be related with this (just a theory).

Answer (score 1):

As per [Chapter 60](https://archive.org/details/KalikaPuranamVol.2AcharyaMrityunjayaTripathi/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater) of Kalika Purana, Mahishasura is said to be a partial incarnation of Shiva in a certain kalpa.

[image]

As per the text, He is said to have taken this partial form in order to bear Devi alongside Simha-rupi Vishnu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laxmi is suppose to be born as Tulsi. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulasi_in_Hinduism